# Business Logic Design

Tags: database, design-patterns

I'm Developing a website using asp.net and sql server i'm using EF with the code first approach as a Data access layer, and the business logic layer(BLL) i've developed a class for each entity that contains functions to query the data base and return object of this entity, my question is about the where i can implement functions that returns data from different tables not from only one table in the BLL.

Answer (score 0):

DAO layer is supposed to create model objects from underlying datastore. In some cases, to create a particular model, different tables have to be queried. In this case, it will be the DAO that will interact with multiple tables (not the service).

BLL might deal with different models in the same service. However, it should depend on one DAO for one model.

In other words, DAOs are mapped to model classes not underlying tables.